# Grey shaded view overlaps the search bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

My view controller has a UISearchDisplayController having a search bar. Below this search bar there is a table view that is hidden initially. When the search string is given the table becomes visible and shows the search results. The search bar behaves normally without any issues in iOS 5 and 6. However in iOS 7, the search bar looks different.

When I click inside the search bar a translucent grey shaded overlay image springs up from nowhere and this overlaps my search bar. When I start typing, suddenly the table view becomes visible and this overlaps the search bar, so I can't see the search bar anymore. However I'm able to type and when the search is given the search results are correctly displayed in the table view. 
What should I do to prevent this overlay image and table view to overlap my search bar ? Is there any property in search bar which I have to set in order to prevent this grey shade from appearing ? I tried resizing the table view but was unsuccessful. Any suggestions from your side would be welcome. Thanks in advance.